# Resolving Shift/reduce conflicts in GNU Bison

Tags: parsing, bison

I have the following grammar rules:

```cpp
%precedence KW2
%left "or"
%left "and"
%left "==" "!=" ">=" ">" "<=" "<"
%left "-" "+"
%left "/" "*"

%start statement1

%%

param
    : id
    | id ":" expr        // Conflict is caused by this line
    | id "=" expr
    ;

param_list
    : param_list "," param
    | param
    ;

defparam
    : param_list "," "/"
    | param_list "," "/" ","
    ;

param_arg_list
    : defparam param_list
    | param_list
    ;

statement1
    : KEYWORD1 "(" param_arg_list ")" ":" expr {}

expression1
    : KEYWORD2 param_arg_list ":" expr %prec KW2 {} // This causes shift/reduce conflicts

expr
    : id

    | expr "+" expr
    | expr "-" expr
    | expr "*" expr
    | expr "/" expr

    | expr "==" expr
    | expr "!=" expr
    | expr "<" expr
    | expr "<=" expr
    | expr ">" expr
    | expr ">=" expr
    | expr "and" expr
    | expr "or" expr
    | expression1

id
    : TK_NAME {}
```

`.output`

```cpp
State 33

   12 param: id .  [":", ",", ")"]
   13      | id . ":" expr
   14      | id . "=" expr

    ":"  shift, and go to state 55
    "="  shift, and go to state 56

    ":"       [reduce using rule 12 (param)]
    $default  reduce using rule 12 (param)
```

The problem here is that, For the `expression1`, `id ":" expr` rule in `param` is not required, so If I remove `id ":" expr`, the conflicts are resolved. But, I can not remove `id ":" expr` rule in `param`, because `statement1` requires it.
I wanted to use `para_arg_list` for `statement1` and `expression1` is that, it simplifies the grammar rules by not allowing to use the grammar rules again and again.
My question is that is there any other way to resolve the conflict?

Comment: Please include a small but complete grammar which shows the problem. (That is, cut the grammar down to a minimum and verify that it produces a similar shift-reduce conflict.) I have no idea how `%prec KW2` fits into your various precedence declarations or the context in which `statement1` and `expression1` might be used, making it impossible for me to provide anything like a suggested fix. See the description of a [mre] in the SO help pages.

Comment: @rici I have updated the grammar rules in the example. Also, the conflict is not caused by the precedence, the grammar rule itself causes it, I believe.

Comment: And what's `statement2`?

Comment: `statement2` is renamed to `expression1`. I used the `%prec KW2` to resolve the conflicts between the `expr` non-terminal nodes

Comment: OK. You could have just put `":"` into the precedence list, and avoided the need to define a pseudo-token, since `":"` is the last token in that production. But that has nothing to do with the ambiguity with colons.  What do you mean by "For `expression1`, the rule `param: id ":" expr` is **not required**"? Do you mean that although that production is present in the grammar, you would consider it a syntax error? Or are you trying to say that the `":" expr` at the end of a subexpression starting with `KEYWORD2`  is required and therefore should take precedence over including it in `param`?

Comment: Neither of those are going to be easy to implement. In the first case, you could just use two different `param_arg_list` definitions, although that will create a little bit of grammar duplication (at least, from the excerpt that's visible to me; maybe there's more to it in the part I can't see.) The second one is probably possible, but I don't think it will be very pretty.

Comment: I got the answer to the question (the first case, I had the same answer. I just wanted to confirm whether my answer is more efficient or any other ways to simplify things), Thank you! But, can you please elaborate more on the second possible case? How do I implement it?

Comment: I'll see what I can do. But until I get around to it, you might want to take a look at [this answer on cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/68880/4416), which shows how to write an unambiguous grammar for dangling elses, in which each `else` is matched with the *outermost* `if` instead of the innermost one. (It works, but it's not very pretty.)